# higher direct images of relative canonical sheaf plus a fractional divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

For a map $f: Y \rightarrow X$ smooth outside a simple normal crossing divisor $B=\sum_iB_i$, do we know of similar local freeness property for higher direct image of relative canonical sheaf plus a fractional divisor supported on the preimage of the branched locus? i.e. is $R^qf_*M$ also locally free, where M is cartier and is numerically equivalent to $K_{Y/X} + \sum_id_iB'_i$? Here, $B' = \sum_iB'_i= (f^*B)_{red}$ and $\lfloor  \sum_id_iB'_i \rfloor = 0$

A relatively unrelated question: do we know anything about how the preimage of the branched locus could look like?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but check Vieweg's vanishing theorems plus Kollar's vanishing of the higher direct images of $\omega$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean here. Do you mean $R^qf_*M$ where $M$ is Cartier and numerically equivalent to $K_{X/Y}+\sum d_iB_i$? In this case it should be true (as long as $(X,\sum d_iB_i)$ is klt). Otherwise the only natural interpretation for $R^qf_*(K_{Y/X}+\sum d_iB_i)$ is to round up or down the coefficients. At any rate, there are many results on this (beginning with Koll\'ar's thms) see eg. the theorem on page 3 of arXiv:math/0302073 Higher direct images of log canonical divisors and positivity theorems. by O. Fujino

Comment: Ah sorry and yes I meant a cartier divisor numerically equivalent to that. I made the necessary change in the question. Thanks professor Hacon.
Could we say anything about the coefficients of the pull back of the branched locus, in the general case?
Also, thank you for the reference.

Comment: When you say branched, do you mean that $f:Y\to X$ is generically finite? or are you thinking of an algebraic fiber space i.e. $f_*O_Y=O_X$ and $\dim X_y>0$? In the generically finite case we write $K_Y+G_Y=f^*(K_X+G)$ where $G=\sum d_iB_i$ and then $(Y,G_Y)$ is lc/klt iff so is $(X,G)$ (see 5.20 of Koll\'ar-Mori).